# Why FFT function in R does not work for a vector of a certain length?

Tags: r, fft, convolution

I'm trying to use fft function in R. Now I know how to apply zero-padding to apply linear convolution. However, for a vector of a certain length (after padding), 415999, R program fails to give the result.

```
x=rnorm(415999)
fft(x)
```

But it works well for a even longer vector.

```
x=rnorm(515999)
fft(x)
```

I'm really confused and hope to get some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in the help file it says

> The FFT is fastest when the length of the series being transformed is highly composite (i.e., has many factors). If this is not the case, the transform may take a long time to compute and will use a large amount of memory.

Take a look at why according to the answer given in my comment to this answer.

Comment: Here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158403/can-a-vector-function-be-considered-a-composite-function and section 2: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psd/vignettes/fftw.pdf